# AWS data transfer Estimates in a distributed set up

Tags: amazon-web-services, cassandra, hazelcast

I would like to understand how we can estimate the data transfer costs.

let me explain the set up,

I have a rest endpoint for accessing data from our caches for multiple users in multiple regions on the cloud.

the set up consists of cassandra, hazelcast caches for data storage. the added complexity is in having the source of the data to cassandra from components in on-premise server

**Cassandra Set up:**

cassandra nodes spread across the AZs. these are in two regions (UK and HK). streaming services from US, ME on premise servers access the data but only when the data is not present in our Hazelcast caches. the **UK cassandra instance replicates data to HK instance for data consistency**

**HZ set up:**
HZ caches are set up in 5 regions as a local cache. these caches sync up using a bidirectional sync. when a data is not found in the cache to serve a rest call, it initiates a gprc call from a service to pull the data to pull the missing data

my method of estimating data transfer is

for api, payload * number of requests in a day

How do I estimate the data transfer for cassandra replication ( includes the gossip ) and Hazelcast Replication across regions ?

Answer (score 1):

For the Hazelcast part, if you enable diagnostics logging on the Hazelcast member, you can read the following metrics: `bytesReceived` and `bytesSent`.

Read more at: https://groups.google.com/g/hazelcast/c/IDIynkEG1YE